# Strange behavior of Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am doing iOS project in Xcode . It was working properly but now it is giving me strange character in place of space.It is also reflecting in all Xcode projects.

[image]

why this is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in xCode go to Menu->Editor->Hide invisible Characters

Why is this happening? because sometimes you need to know if your indentation or spacing is correct, or even you want to know if you are using spaces or tabs, then you will Show Invisibles, it maybe useful sometimes

[image]